# How to Map an object with nested icollection to a list of dto

Tags: c#, automapper, mapper

```
class One 
{
public Guid Id { get; set;}
public string Name { get; set;}
public string Number { get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Two> Comments { get; set;}
}

class Two 
{
 public Guid Id { get; set;}
 public string Text { get; set; }
 public DateTime date {get; set;}
 public virtual ICollection<Three> Likes { get; set; }
}

class Three {
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
 public string EmojiName { get; set; }
}
```

I created dto class:

```
class MainDto 
{
public stirng Name { get; set;}
public stirng Text{ get; set;}
public stirng EmojiName { get; set;}
}
```

I need to map data from class One to MainDto, but I do not know how. I added class tmp:

```
class tmp {
public string Number { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public string EmojiName { get; set; }
}
```

And I tried use converter in mapping profile:

```
profile.CreateMap<One, IList<tmp>>()
.ConvertUsing(o => o.One.Comments.SelectMany(tw => tw.Likes).Select(th => new tmp
{ Name = o.Name, Text = tw.Text, EmojiName = th.EmojiName }
).ToList())
```

and I thought it was enough to just use the mapper to map List to List  and then the result of it map to list but gets return the collection empty.
is there any other way?

Comment: so you have an `IEnumerable<One>` and want to get back an `IEnumerable<MainDtO>` ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do with an automapper

Comment: Before you call the mapper.Map<source, destination>(model), do you populate ICollection<Two> Comments? like:                 var resultsFromDb = await applicationDbContext
                    .PracticeAreas.Include(x => x.Person_PracticeAreas).ThenInclude(p => p.Person)
                    .ToListAsync();
                return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PracticeArea>, IEnumerable<PracticeAreaDTO>>(resultsFromDb);

Comment: yea, I have a One object that has a object two inside it that contains a object three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CreateMap<One, IList<MainDto>>().ConvertUsing(o => o.Comments.SelectMany(tw => tw.Likes.Select(th => new MainDto() { Name = o.Name, Text = tw.Text, EmojiName = th.EmojiName, })).ToList());
```

You don't need "class tmp".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linq solution. Probably not the fastest but I think its self documenting.

```
List<One> ones = GetOnes();
List<MainDto> mains = ones.Select(x => {
    var comment = x.Comments.First(y => y.Id == x.Id);
    var like = comment.Likes.First(z => z.Id == x.Id);
    return new MainDto()
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Text = comment.Text,
        EmojiName = like.EmojiName
    };
}).ToList();
```

Comment: can it be done with automapper?